# How do I calculate the total ammount of dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I'm a graphic designer not a programmer
But I followed some tutorials to make a commission for online form webpage

I wanna know how to calculate the prices in this table ( total for the distributor and second total for the public ) >.> I know it's very complicated .

I tried to add cwolves answer to the code page .. but it conflicts with my submit button .. can't it appears automatically without buttons .. appears somewhere below the table ?

you can take a look at this table here: http://jsfiddle.net/87JpK/

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="125" height="30"><div align="left"><em3>&nbsp;Product's Name</em3></div></td>
    <td width="85"><div align="left"><em3>Volume ml</em3></div></td>
    <td width="110"><div align="left"><em3>Distributor</em3></div></td>
    <td width="110"><div align="left"><em3>Public</em3></div></td>
    <td width="200"><div align="left"><em3>Quantity (1 Pack=10 Units)</em3></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30"><label for="face_cream">&nbsp;&nbsp;<em4>Face Cream</em4></label></td>
    <td>120</td>
    <td>&nbsp;21.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td>&nbsp;35.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td><select name="face_cream" id="face_cream">
      <option value="0 Pack" selected="selected">Choose your quantity...</option>
      <option value="1 Pack">1 Pack</option>
      <option value="2 Packs">2 Packs</option>
      <option value="3 Packs">3 Packs</option>
      ...
      <option value="99 Packs">99 Packs</option>
      <option value="100 Packs">100 Packs</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30"><label for="body_cream">&nbsp;&nbsp;<em4>Body Cream</em4></label></td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>&nbsp;36.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td>&nbsp;59.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td><select name="body_cream" id="body_cream">
      <option value="0 Pack" selected="selected">Choose your quantity...</option>
      <option value="1 Pack">1 Pack</option>
      <option value="2 Packs">2 Packs</option>
      <option value="3 Packs">3 Packs</option>
      ...
      <option value="99 Packs">99 Packs</option>
      <option value="100 Packs">100 Packs</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30"><label for="body_oil">&nbsp;&nbsp;<em4>Body Oil</em4></label></td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>&nbsp;31.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td>&nbsp;53.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td><select name="body_oil" id="body_oil">
      <option value="0 Pack" selected="selected">Choose your quantity...</option>
      <option value="1 Pack">1 Pack</option>
      <option value="2 Packs">2 Packs</option>
      <option value="3 Packs">3 Packs</option>
      ...
      <option value="99 Packs">99 Packs</option>
      <option value="100 Packs">100 Packs</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30"><label for="face_wash">&nbsp;&nbsp;<em4>Face Wash</em4></label></td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>&nbsp;26.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td>&nbsp;39.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td><select name="face_wash" id="face_wash">
      <option value="0 Pack" selected="selected">Choose your quantity...</option>
      <option value="1 Pack">1 Pack</option>
      <option value="2 Packs">2 Packs</option>
      <option value="3 Packs">3 Packs</option>
     ...
      <option value="99 Packs">99 Packs</option>
      <option value="100 Packs">100 Packs</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="30"><label for="breast_oil">&nbsp;&nbsp;<em4>Breast Oil</em4></label></td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>&nbsp;30.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td>&nbsp;49.00&nbsp;&nbsp;<em2>(CHF)</em2></td>
    <td><select name="breast_oil" id="breast_oil">
      <option value="0 Pack" selected="selected">Choose your quantity...</option>
      <option value="1 Pack">1 Pack</option>
      <option value="2 Packs">2 Packs</option>
      <option value="3 Packs">3 Packs</option>
     ...
      <option value="99 Packs">99 Packs</option>
      <option value="100 Packs">100 Packs</option>
      </select></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ER...why put all that in a dropdown list?  Dropdowns are supposed to make looking things up easier, or restrict options.  In this case, you might be better served with a textbox that the user could enter a number in, no?

Comment: A `<input type="number" />` would be better.  Unless there's a way to buy in different unit types, there's no reason to make it part of the form element.

Comment: The question is not clear. Where are the prices? Do you want to calculate *after* the user chooses and submits this form?

Comment: I want the calculation appears below the table when the user chooses the quantity before pressing submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eh, why not.  Using jQuery:

```
eval( $( 'td:nth-child(3)' ).map( function( td, $this ){
    return ( ( parseFloat( ( $this = $( this ) ).text() ) || 0 )
        * ( parseFloat( $this.parent().find( 'select' ).val() ) || 0 ) );
} ).get().join( '+' ) )
```

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/W8yK8/

change the `nth-child(3)` to a `4` for public price

(and to anyone that wants to criticize me, this is the same quality as the question itself)

Comment: LOL.  Nice job in any case.

Comment: that's a mean comment .. I'm a super beginner

Comment: Ok cwolves thank you it works with me .. but when I tried to add it to the code page .. it conflicts with my submit button .. can't it appears automatically without buttons .. appears somewhere below the table ?